# Getting average of one column in a nested SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I'll try to simplify this for simplicity's sake. I need to get the average value of a returned column of a query. Make sense? I'll try to elaborate.(Sample results borrowed from another question)

```
Plant_ID | Year |Quarter| MR  | Range
| CCAR   | 2009 | 1     | 706 | Null
| CCAR   | 2009 | 2     | 626 | 0,08
| CCAR   | 2009 | 2     | 637 | 0,11
| CCAR   | 2009 | 2     | 737 | 0,1
| CCAR   | 2009 | 1     | 552 | 0,19
| CCAR   | 2009 | 4     | 418 | 0,137
| CCAR   | 2009 | 1     | 503 | 0,085
| CCAR   | 2009 | 2     | 645 | 0,058
| CCAR   | 2009 | 4     | 743 | 0,098
| CCAR   | 2009 | 3     | 556 | 0,187
| CCAR   | 2009 | 1     | 298 | 0,258
| CCAR   | 2009 | 2     | 339 | 0,041
| CCAR   | 2010 | 1     | 381 | 0,042
```

I would get this result when I run a query like this

```
Select PlantID, Year, Quarter, MR, Range FROM TestTable WHERE PlantID in('CCAR')
```

I want the average MR for each quarter. Preliminarily I would try something like this.

```
Select Quarter, AVG(MR) FROM (Select PlantID, Year, Quarter, MR, Range FROM TestTable WHERE PlantID in ('CCAR')) GROUP BY Quarter ORDER BY Quarter
```

The issue is that I don't know where to nest the query to accomplish this. Any help?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any reason why the inline view would be necessary. As for your second query, what is wrong with the output? It seems syntactically valid although it wouldn't be any different if you just grabbed the average for each MR in the inner query.

Comment: I agree with Brian. From the requirements you've specified there isn't a need for nesting. You may simply run the aggregation query directly on the table.

Comment: So you're saying just to say "Select Quarter, Avg(MR) FROM TestTable WHERE PlantID in ('CCAR') Group by Quarter"?

Comment: Do you want separate averages for different *years* or will you group all, let say, 1st quarters together?

Answer (score 0):

Add an alias e.g. hallo

```
Select Quarter, AVG(MR) FROM 
(Select PlantID, Year, Quarter, MR, Range FROM TestTable WHERE PlantID in ('CCAR')) hallo    
GROUP BY Quarter ORDER BY Quarter
```

while this is not necessary in this case, the following would be enough

```
Select Quarter, AVG(MR)
FROM TestTable 
WHERE PlantID in ('CCAR')   
GROUP BY Quarter 
ORDER BY Quarter
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use aggregation:

```
select Year, Quarter, avg(MR)
from TestTable
where PlantID in ('CCAR')
group by Year, Quarter;
```

I presume you want the year with the quarter.  If not, just remove year from the `select` and `group by`.